# Check if date is between the start of May this year and the end of May next year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a query that returns a date. eg 2013-10-12.

I want to check if the date is between June 1st of the year and the last day of the year.

If it is between these dates increase the year by 1 else leave the year as it is.

So, taking the example above `2013-10-12` the result I want is 2014.
If it was `2013-01-12` the result I want is 2013.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are you asking, in quite a roundabout fashion, for some way of taking a date and working out which financial year it belongs to? If so, can you clarify between your title and the body of your question when your financial years actually run though - is it May or June?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Yourdate datetime = '2013-10-13'

SELECT CASE WHEN 
(@Yourdate between '2013-06-01' and  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()) + 1, -1) ) 
THEN YEAR(@Yourdate) + 1 ELSE (YEAR(@Yourdate) ) END AS [YEAR]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @arg datetime
set @arg = '01/12/2013'

select 
case when month(@arg) > 5 then year(@arg) + 1 else year(@arg) end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @var varchar(20) = '2013-01-12';

select case when Month(convert(datetime,@var ,120)) > 5 then Year(convert(datetime,@var ,120)) + 1 else Year(convert(datetime,@var ,120)) end
```